# Python Turtle for loop running infinitely

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have some Turtle code that I've successfully run before to draw the Sierpinski Gasket in Repl.it's Python with Turtle IDE, but recently when I've tried to run it again, it successfully does everything except once it hits the for loop, the turtle just starts spinning and doesn't execute the lines in the for loop until much later.

I've added a print(i) into the forloop and it is printing 0 repeatedly as if it were an infinite loop

```
import turtle
from turtle import *

t = Turtle()
t.speed(0)
t.shape('turtle')
t.color('dark green')

def SGRules(char):
  if char == 'F':
    return 'F+F-F-F+F'
  else:
    return char

def processStr(oldstr, Fractal_Rules):
  newstr = ""
  for char in oldstr:
    newstr = newstr + Fractal_Rules(char)
  return newstr

def createLSystem(iteration, axiom, Fractal_Rules):
  startstr = axiom
  endstr = ""
  for i in range(iteration):
    endstr = processStr(startstr, Fractal_Rules)
    startstr = endstr
  return endstr

def drawLSystem(aturtle, lsys, angle, length):
  for cmd in lsys:
    if cmd == 'F':
      aturtle.forward(length)
    elif cmd == '+':
      aturtle.left(angle)
    elif cmd == '-':
      aturtle.right(angle)

sgstr = createLSystem(4, 'F', SGRules)
print(sgstr)
drawLSystem(t, sgstr, 120, 20)
for i in range(2):
  print(i)
  t.left(120)
  t.forward(20 * 2**4)
```

It should just draw the 2 sides of the outer triangle remaining as soon as it reaches the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cleanup of your code runs fine for me on repl.it and in the Python console:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

ANGLE = 120
LENGTH = 20
ITERATIONS = 4

def SGRules(character):
    if character == 'F':
        return 'F+F-F-F+F'

    return character

def processStr(string, rules):
    new_string = ""

    for character in string:
        new_string += rules(character)

    return new_string

def createLSystem(iterations, axiom, rules):
    string = ""

    for _ in range(iterations):
        string = processStr(axiom, rules)
        axiom = string

    return string

def drawLSystem(turtle, lsys, angle, length):
    for command in lsys:
        if command == 'F':
            turtle.forward(length)
        elif command == '+':
            turtle.left(angle)
        elif command == '-':
            turtle.right(angle)

yertle = Turtle('turtle')
yertle.speed('fastest')
yertle.shape('turtle')
yertle.color('dark green', 'light green')

sg_string = createLSystem(ITERATIONS, 'F', SGRules)
print(sg_string)
drawLSystem(yertle, sg_string, ANGLE, LENGTH)

for _ in range(2):
    yertle.left(ANGLE)
    yertle.forward(LENGTH * 2 ** ITERATIONS)

screen = Screen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Though your original code worked fine in the Python console once I added a transfer to tkinter's event loop at the end to keep the window from closing.